# global messages is not working in magento

Tags: flash, magento, notifications, global, message

In Default, Magento provide global messages(flash messages) to display success,Error and Notice after page loading.For us, global messages is not working anywhere ( front-end and admin-side ) . If anyone faced this issue, please provide your suggestion to resolve this issue .Thanks!

Comment: check var/session folder are there?

Comment: Qaisar, We used database session for our project. So that we can't track session in 'var/session' folder. I checked in magento session table. Here we can see some sessions. But i can't find sessions for global messaging

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a code on how you display an error message?

This is the way you could add a Magento notification in admin panel

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess("Message"); //or addError();
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, If problem in single page or single module, we can add specific code. Bit it is not working anywhere(front-end and admin side) messages ( success,notice and error )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nexcessnet_Turpentine, check if the extension is enabled at

Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Disable Modules Output

because Nexcessnet_Turpentine_Block_Core_Messages rewrites Mage_Core_Block_Messages

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: @Nilambar if Nexcessnet_Turpentine is 'Disabled' on "Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Disable Modules Output"  - messages will not be shown